# load in jQuery doesn't work in Chrome nor Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, safari, ahah

[UPDATE] It only works in Firefox and not at Chrome nor Safari.
I am following a [jQuery tutorial (AHAH)](http://www.lynda.com/Ajax-tutorials/AHAH-simpler-case/150163/155368-4.html) but the description doesn't show up in the "show more" section when I click on the flowers.

[image]
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

```
var $flowers = $('#flower-items');

$('#flower-items').find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $desc = $('#flower-description');

    switch($(this).attr('href')) {
        case 'calla.html' :
            $desc.load('fragments/lilies.html');
            break;
        case 'sunflowers.html' :
            $desc.load('fragments/sunflower.html');
            break;
        case 'iris.html' :
            $desc.load('fragments/irises.html');
            break;
        case 'alstromeria.html' :
            $desc.load('fragments/peruvian.html');
            break;
    }
```

here's the folder structure:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your jQuery.js file?

Comment: Have you tried watching your console in your browser to see if you are accessing the HTML files correctly?

Comment: Can you include your HTML? We need to see the hrefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in CHROME:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<ul id="flower-items">
    <li><a href="calla.html">Flower 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="sunflowers.html">Flower 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="iris.html">Flower 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="alstromeria.html">Flower 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="5.html">Flower 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="6.html">Flower 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="7.html">Flower 7</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="flower-description">Flower Description</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $flowers = $('#flower-items');

    $('#flower-items').find('a').on('click', function(e){
        alert('a');
        e.preventDefault();

        var $desc = $('#flower-description');

        switch($(this).attr('href')) {
            case 'calla.html' :
                alert('b')
                $desc.load('fragments/lilies.html');
                break;
            case 'sunflowers.html' :
                $desc.load('fragments/sunflower.html');
                break;
            case 'iris.html' :
                $desc.load('fragments/irises.html');
                break;
            case 'alstromeria.html' :
                $desc.load('fragments/peruvian.html');
                break;
        }
    })

})
</script>
```

You should see this in console:

[image]